# arcGIS ADF - map disappear when I add graphic layers

Tags: c#, asp.net, gis, arcgis, arcgis-server

I'm trying to add a graphic layer in a web ADF application with arcGIS for asp.net, but every time I add a graphic layer to the MapResourceManager, the map disappears!

To better understand this: here's the simple app with the only element in the MapResourceManager being the map service (OGC (WMS) Service) which provides me the map

http://imageshack.us/f/715/pro2w.jpg/

And here's the MapResourceManager with another graphic layer, the map misteriously disappears

http://imageshack.us/f/543/pro1y.jpg/

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out, warning: javascript at line indicated by javascript debuggers like firebug or chrome's integrated one is bugged, combobox name is case-sensitive and you need to correct it